# How to solve a Froala-editor's problem for Angular app V15 and the webpack used is 5.75.0

Tags: css, angular, upgrade, webpack-5, froala

I had V12 Angular App that I'm working on.
I wanted to upgrade it to V15.
I faced this problem during ng serve with froala-editor.

./node_modules/froala-editor/css/froala_style.min.css?ngGlobalStyle:7:0 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

I think that the version used of webpack couldn't load this file type.
I don't have webpack.config.js in my root.
Once I created, I've faced other type of bugs.

Angular.json:

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/froala-editor/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css",
              "node_modules/froala-editor/css/froala_style.min.css",
             
            
             
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/echarts/dist/echarts.min.js",
              "node_modules/froala-editor/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js",
             
            ],
``
```

```
index.html:

<link href="/node_modules/froala-editor/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

```
app.modules:
....
import {FroalaEditorModule, FroalaViewModule} from 'angular-froala-wysiwyg';
.......
    FroalaEditorModule.forRoot(),
    FroalaViewModule.forRoot(),
```